# Positioning Item directly after wrapped <UL>

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am trying to build a responsive website and have a list of 6 credit cards that are accepted on my site being displayed in a ul as logos of the cards accepts.

Directly after the logos I have a link to a popup giving more information about the types of cards accepted.

The code looks as follows.

```css
.icon-list,
.icon-list li{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-icons">
     <ul class="icon-list horizontal">
      <li class="icon icon-card-visa">
       //visa icon
      </li>
      <li class="icon icon-card-visa-debit">
       //visa debit icon
      </li>
      <li class="icon icon-card-mastercard">
       //mastercard icon
      </li>
      <li class="icon icon-card-american-express">
       //american express icon
      </li>
      <li class="icon icon-card-maestro">
       //maestro icon
      </li>
     </ul>
     <a href="/help-page/credit-cards" target="_blank">
      //help icon
     </a>
    </div>
```

I can align the popup to sit alongside the icon-list using display:inline-block for larger viewports. When I go down to mobile viewport though and the icons wrap onto 2 lines in the list, the help logo stacks underneath the ul. If you run the code snippet in full size view and then reduce the window to a mobile viewport size you will see the issue.

How can I go about fixing this so the help icon always sits alongside the icon-list, without adding the help-icon to the list of cards?

N.B I am unable to change the content of the icon-list.

Comment: Where is the CSS? You'll have to write a media query for it.

Comment: Could you be more clear? I would expect help to come **after** the card icons, which is what I understand to be, _"sits underneath the list."_ Is the icon actually underneath the list, like a stack of papers? Where the list of cards is the top sheet of paper and the help icon is the second sheet, under the first.

Comment: Sorry was a little unclear. 

Yes the help icon stacks underneath the card icons when the card icons start wrapping. I would like the help icon to sit alongside the card icons, so that it looks like 1 list.

Comment: @Phil please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way we can see what CSS you have applied to your list and help icon. Mind that you don't have to include a complete page's worth of HTML & CSS, just that parts to reproduce your problem. Also, it would be a good idea to update your question with the info above so it's more obvious for those looking to help as they don't need to weed through comments to understand the finer points.

Comment: Have just done this :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Design! You can also fork design code from my [Github](https://github.com/momin-ctg/ecommerce_footer) repository

```css
ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:block;
}

li{
float:left;
list-style:none;
padding:10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Useful informations</h3>
  <p>Some informations you need to know.</p>
  <h4>Payments Method</h4>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/QwpoxK2.png" alt="paypal"></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/HibdwbY.png" alt="discover"></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/6key80n.png" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Dt1meTr.png" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/0jW3wVM.png" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/EvzaxAf.png" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```